# How do I make a UILabel *not* pass touches to the UITableViewCell it's embedded in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` with a bunch of cells, and I add a `UILabel` to each. I want the `UILabel`, when tapped, to accept the touches, not the cell. Obviously if they tap outside of the label and still on the cell that is fine, but if it's on the label the cell should not cause a segue or action or whatever, only the label's action on tap should fire.

My normal method to cause this is to set the `UIView`'s `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`, but in this case when I set it on the label it doesn't cause anything different to happen. When I watch `touchesBegan` in the label subclass those methods do fire, but the cell selection does as well.

How do I make the `UILabel` not pass the touches on to the cell?

Comment: Where is your `touchesBegan` method (which class)?

Comment: In my UILabel subclass.

Comment: You didn't mention you have a `UILabel` subclass which is why I asked.

Comment: Totally understand. Added to the main post.

Comment: What code do you have in the touchesBegan method?

Comment: @rdelmar Nothing, just an NSLog indicating it has been tapped.

Comment: I can't duplicate that behavior. If I override touchesBegan in a custom label, I don't get any pass through to the cell, and I do see the logs in that method.

Comment: I'll add a sample project shortly.

Comment: @rdelmar Here's a sample project: http://cl.ly/0X1s0v2p3G2m

Comment: Doug, you don't just have a log in there, you're calling super -- that's what's causing the touch to be passed to the cell.

Comment: Oh. I thought passing that it to super was standard. What exactly does passing it to the super class cause here, it's not passing it to the super *view*, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67430/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-doug-smith).

Comment: It passes it to the superclass, UILabel, which, I presume, doesn't implement touchesDown, so it automatically gets passed up the responder chain.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label and setting [`cancelsTouchesInView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView) property to YES to prevent the touches from being delivered to the view upon gesture recognition, ex:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
labelTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[label addGestureRecognizer:labelTapGesture];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

And since you don't want the gesture to perform an action, you can set its action to nil.

Comment: Does it require a gesture recognizer? I was hoping to just use the built in touchesBegan method.

Comment: @DougSmith Yeah, it requires a gesture recognizer. I'll update to clarify.